# RAID 1 Status

Tags: raid

In a RAID 1 that is going bad what does the status's "Current" and "dropped" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steven and David has already mentioned, you have not provided enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

I'd suggest that you read Eric Raymond's essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and then edit your question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide a lot more detail.  What controller?  What OS?  What tool?  What context?

Generally I'd say dropped would mean a bad drive (failed, faulty, etc), if its listed beside a drive.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give more details (OS, hardware RAID controller or software? which controller/software?, how are you reading these status?, can you give a fuller readout instead of just those two words?, ...) to get a genuinely useful answer.

If I were to hazard a guess, I would say that "dropped" indicates a drive that the controller/software has determined is bad and has been dropped from the array and needs replacing.